# Is there a term for a page layout with one column having no body text?

Tags: page-layout, terminology

There is a technique in book design that creates a very wide outer (or sometimes inner) margin to the body text, allowing the lay-outer to put parts of the content in there. Think of annotations, comments, or having an image edge into the 'spare column'.

I've seen this design regularly in magazine design, and sometimes in textbooks. The size of the spare column can vary, but it's common to have eg. a four-column page and then have the body text only occupy three of those, rendering one column 'spare'.

This image is an example:

[image: a page spread design with three columns to each page. Body text is limited to the inner two columns, the outer column contains annotations. On one page, an image is half in the outer column, half in one of the body text columns.]

Is there a term for this type of layout, or for the spare column? I know there is one in Dutch ('vluchtkolom', lit. 'refuge column'), but can't think of an English one.